# Boolean type with PostgreSQL in Yii

Tags: yii

Simple Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  val BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

**Do this**:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insert('test', array(
        'id'=>1,
        'val'=>true,
    ));
```

Everithing's allright:

```
Executing SQL: INSERT INTO "test" ("id", "val") VALUES (:id, :val). Bound with :id=1, :val=true
```

But **doing this**

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insert('test', array(
        'id'=>1,
        'val'=>false,
    ));
```

I'm getting the **error**:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: ""
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "test" ("id", "val") VALUES ('1', '')
^. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO "test" ("id", "val") VALUES (:id, :val). Bound with :id=1, :val=false
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: Php is casting the boolean to integer, and in the case of 'false' value, is converted to "". Take a look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33876#1122477362

Comment: The emphasis is on casting types in PDO, and your link is very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now there is an issue on Yii GitHub:
http://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/779

Comment: Please post your 'db' component settings.

Answer (score 1):

In your 'db' component, set [**emulatePrepare**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#emulatePrepare-detail) property to false/null. Setting it to true usually triggers this error.

*Postgres Supports prepared statements so there is no need to emulate.*